# Find bound for $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n \sin \pi s}{n!(n+1-s)\pi}$

Tags: complex-analysis

We have the sum
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n \sin \pi s}{n!(n+1-s)\pi}$$ for all $s$ with $|\text{Im}(s)|\le1$
This is a step from the proof of growth order of Gamma function by E.Stein in his Complex analysis.

Here for each $|\text{Im}(s)\le1|$ exists integer $k$ such that $k-1/2\le \text{Re}(s)<k+1/2$ (here I only need to consider $k>0$, otherwise trivial). Now truncate this sum into $$\sum_{n\neq k-1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n\sin \pi s}{n!(n+1-s)\pi}+\frac{(-1)^{k-1} \sin \pi s}{(k-1)!(k-s)\pi}.$$
For the first term, it is clear that $1/2 \le n+1-s$ therefore the whole term is bounded by $C|\sin \pi s|$ for some constant $C$ and therefore bounded by $Ce^{\pi|s|}$. But for the second term, I know $\sin\pi s$ also has a simple zero at $k$， so $\frac{(-1)^{k-1} \sin \pi s}{(k-1)!(k-s)\pi}=\frac{(-1)^{k-1} h(s)}{(k-1)!\pi}$ for some analytic $h$, with $h$ bounded by $C_s$ on $\{(x,y): k-1/2\le x<k+1/2, |y|\le1 \}$ but $C_s$ depends on $k$ and $k$ depends on $s$, so $\frac{(-1)^{k-1} \sin \pi s}{(k-1)!(k-s)\pi}$ is bounded by $C_s$ is saying nothing but $\frac{(-1)^{k-1} \sin \pi s}{(k-1)!(k-s)\pi}$ well defined on $\{(x,y):|y|\le1\}$. Is there a way to find the bound independent of $s$ for $\frac{(-1)^{k-1} \sin \pi s}{(k-1)!(k-s)\pi}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you wanted to say $k - 1/2 \le \operatorname{Re}(s) \le k + 1/2$. Note also that $\sin(\pi s)$ has a simple zero at $k$, not a simple pole. Furthermore,
$$
( - 1)^{k - 1} \frac{{\sin (\pi s)}}{{(k - s)\pi }} = \frac{{\sin ((k - s)\pi )}}{{(k - s)\pi }}
$$
and
$$
\left| {\frac{{\sin ((k - s)\pi )}}{{(k - s)\pi }}} \right| \le \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{\left| {(k - s)\pi } \right|^{2n} }}{{(2n + 1)!}}}  \le \mathrm{e}^{\left| {(k - s)\pi } \right|^2 }  \le K
$$
in a compact neighbourhood of $k$. If, for example, $k - 1/2 \le \operatorname{Re}(s) \le k + 1/2$ and $|\operatorname{Im}(s)|<1$, then
$$
\left| {(k - s)\pi } \right|^2  = \pi ^2 \left| {\operatorname{Re} (k - s)} \right|^2  + \pi ^2 \left| {\operatorname{Im} (k - s)} \right|^2  \le \frac{{\pi ^2 }}{4} + \pi ^2 ,
$$
i.e., $K = \mathrm{e}^{\frac{{5\pi ^2 }}{4}}$ works.

Comment: Thank your!! I will edit it. I see the point.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an another answer: Note $\frac{\sin s}{s}$ is bounded on $\{(x,y):|y\le 1\}$ due to periodicity of $\sin s$. Therefore, $|\frac{\sin\pi s}{s-k}|$ is also uniformly bounded on $\{(x,y):|y\le 1\}$.